# SQL Server Trigger functioning backwards

Tags: sql-server

I have a little strange issue with my SQL script and I was hoping someone could help me out with it.

I have a Database being created by using

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name
    FROM sysdatabases
    WHERE name = 'travel')
    DROP DATABASE travel
    GO
    CREATE DATABASE travel
GO

USE travel
GO
```

I then create 3 tables as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customerID INT,
    lastname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phoneCheck CHECK ((phone LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
    category VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT categoryDefault DEFAULT 'A',
    CONSTRAINT categoryCheck CHECK (category IN ('A', 'B', 'C')),

    CONSTRAINT customerPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
)

CREATE TABLE package    /*Still need to do the Zero Padding*/
(
    packageCode VARCHAR(6),
    destination VARCHAR(70),
    CONSTRAINT packageCodeCheck CHECK (packageCode LIKE ('YFK%')),
    price MONEY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT priceCheck CHECK ((price BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000)),
    passportRequired VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT passportRequiredDefault DEFAULT 'Y',
    CONSTRAINT passportCheck CHECK (passportRequired IN ('Y', 'N')),

    CONSTRAINT packagePK
        PRIMARY KEY (packageCode)
)

CREATE TABLE booking    /*Still need to do the Customer and Package delete*/
(
    customerID VARCHAR(6),
    bookingDate VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    amountPaid MONEY CONSTRAINT amountPaidDefault DEFAULT 0.00,

    CONSTRAINT bookingPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
)
```

Now heres the issue, I create a trigger as shown below

```
GO

CREATE TRIGGER customerDelete ON customer AFTER DELETE
AS
DELETE booking
FROM customer
WHERE customer.customerID = booking.customerID

GO
```

Which to my understanding it will delete all records in booking... that have the matching customerID WHEN a record is deleted from the customer Table. (I am new to triggers)

I INSERT Sample Data as shown below

```
INSERT INTO customer
    (customerID, lastname, firstname, phone, category)
VALUES
    (1, 'Picard', 'Corey', 1234567890, 'A'),
    (2, 'Bond', 'Devon', 9876543210, 'B'),
    (3, 'Douglas', 'Bryan', 6549871230, 'C')

INSERT INTO package
    (packageCode, destination, price, passportRequired)
VALUES
    ('YFK001', 'Toronto', 1000.57, 'N'),
    ('YFK002', 'Orlando', 3000.98, 'Y')

INSERT INTO booking
    (customerID, bookingDate, amountPaid)
VALUES
    (1, GETDATE(), 1548),
    (2, GETDATE(), 1586),
    (3, GETDATE(), 1350),
    (4, GETDATE(), 1650)
```

And Finally I delete the Customer from the TABLE customer  with the customerID of 1 by using

```
DELETE customer
    WHERE customerID = 1
```

However, when I attempt to see the results by using

```
SELECT * FROM customer
    --WHERE customerID = 1 OR customerID = 2 OR customerID = 3

SELECT * FROM package
    --WHERE packageCode = 'YFK001' OR packageCode = 'YFK002'

SELECT * FROM booking
    --WHERE customerID = 1 OR customerID = 2 OR customerID = 3 OR customerID = 4
```

It displays bookings with customerID 1 and 4.

Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?

The trigger is essentially used for the purpose of deleting the bookings with the same customerID of the customer we delete from the customer TABLE

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: `delete` syntax is `delete from tablename`. you've got `delete booking from customer`. so you're not deleting from your booking table at all. you're trying an illegal delete on the customer table.

Comment: Have you tried keys with cascade during table creation

Comment: I noticed that the primary key for the `booking` table is the `customerID`.  That means each customer can only have one booking in the table.  Are you sure that it what you intend?

Comment: The `Deleted` pseudo table contains those rows that were deleted - you're not referencing that pseudo table in your trigger! You're just deleting **everything** from your table!

Comment: And why is the date column `varchar(70)` rather than `date` and a required flag (constrained to be Y or N) a `varchar(7)` rather than `char(1)`?

Comment: I left out making any changes for some reason I dont understand anymore :) I will update those right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your delete to this:

```
DELETE B
FROM booking B
INNER JOIN DELETED D
    ON B.customerID = D.customerID;
```

Comment: I tried this and the SELECT statement still shows the booking for customerID = 1

Comment: @BryanD I confused the table to perform the delete, try now

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is not trigger, [ If you specially want to use Trigger then You can use Lamak's & Pradeep's Answer]
Here best way you can do is use Cacade on foreign Key in your case

Here is your Query I just updated cascade in it

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customerID INT,
    lastname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phoneCheck CHECK ((phone LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
    category VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT categoryDefault DEFAULT 'A',
    CONSTRAINT categoryCheck CHECK (category IN ('A', 'B', 'C')),

    CONSTRAINT customerPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
)

CREATE TABLE package    /*Still need to do the Zero Padding*/
(
    packageCode VARCHAR(6),
    destination VARCHAR(70),
    CONSTRAINT packageCodeCheck CHECK (packageCode LIKE ('YFK%')),
    price MONEY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT priceCheck CHECK ((price BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000)),
    passportRequired VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT passportRequiredDefault DEFAULT 'Y',
    CONSTRAINT passportCheck CHECK (passportRequired IN ('Y', 'N')),

    CONSTRAINT packagePK
        PRIMARY KEY (packageCode)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE booking    /*Still need to do the Customer and Package delete*/
(
    customerID VARCHAR(6),
    bookingDate VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    amountPaid MONEY CONSTRAINT amountPaidDefault DEFAULT 0.00,

    CONSTRAINT bookingPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

This way when you are deleting or update [keyvalue] any entry of Table holding primary key will update its related foreign childs